# SWFObject Jwplayer Youtube won't play. Was playing alright

Tags: php, youtube, jwplayer, swfobject

I am going crazy here. Please see the example: **[Here](http://1dollar1home.com/projecthome.php?p=8)**

For the longest time can't figure out how to get this player to play youtube codes embeded in code. I figure jwplayer updates is responsible but update the jwplayer.js doesn't show anything at all. I'm very much a novice at php calls etc. Someone point me in the right direction or a better solution. Thank you in advance!

```
<script src="js/global.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type='text/javascript' src='video/swfobject.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pop-style.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
<link href="css/howitworks.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/howitworks.js"></script> 


<!-- Load Video / Image --> 
<div class='projectsh_video'>   

    <?php if ( $objProjects->pro_media_type == 'V' ) : ?>           


        <script type='text/javascript'>                 
            PlayVideo("<?php echo $objProjects->pro_video_link; ?>","525","350","preview");
        </script>
```

Video

```
    <?php else : ?> 

        <img src='<?php echo $objProjects->pro_l_image; ?>' alt='<?php echo $objProjects->pro_title; ?>' title='<?php echo $objProjects->pro_title; ?>' />

    <?php endif; ?>     

</div><!-- End of projectsh_video -->`
```

Comment: It'd be nicer if you showed us the output code too (i.e. what the PHP file outputs).

Comment: I would suggest updating to JW 5.10, but since support for JW 5 has now ended entirely, I'm not sure you could download it anywhere. You should really move to JW6, but that would require some substantial re-coding, since the embedding method is now completely different.

Comment: Thanks for your quick review and suggestions. Do you have any ideas on a fairly easy solution? Users will be including youtube links on their page. The code will involve a php call for whatever their link is to show in their page. The end product should have this link playing correctly. **[link](http://1dollar1home.com/projecthome.php?p=8)**

Comment: This does not work because you are using 5.3, which used YouTube's AS2 API, which is totally deprecated now. If you update to at least 5.6, the YouTube AS3 API is used, which works. I would update to 5.10 if you must stay on JW5, though...

Comment: can you forward me the link to download the 5.10? @Ethan JWPlayer. I'm  really think hard about just sticking with JW Player 6. I wonder how much coding will be required using the existing setup. Any thoughts ideas?

Comment: http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf is what you need. If you want to upgrade to JW6, you need to re-do your embed using the JW Embedder (jwplayer.js)